# please explain strange behaviour of combine with swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

so - I now have working code, but I'm just trying to understand why it didn't work the way I tried it.  So - I made a publisher of images that looks like anyPublisher<UIImage, Never> - and I'm trying to display it on a swiftui panel.

I have now the following:

```swift
    @state var UIImage theImage
    var imageSource : AnyPublisher<UIImage, Never>

    ...

    Image( uiImage: theImage).onReceive(imageSource) {image in self.theImage = image}
```

which works great.  However, before using onReceive, I tried subscribing in the init - ie

```swift
   init()
   {
      ...

      let theSelf = self
      theSelf.subscription = imageSource.sink {image in 
          theSelf.theImage = image
          print("I'm here")
      }
```

I was getting the "I'm here" displayed but the image just wasn't changing - the binding wasn't working for some reason - and I'm just trying to understand why - ie how it can work if I put it in an onreceive block, but it doesn't work if I put it in the sink, and all other code remains identical?      Is it a threading thing?   I tried receiveOn( RunLoop.main) as well as subscribeOn, but that didn't make any difference.   Obviously there's something about property binding I just don't understand, and would like to.  (thanks)

Comment: let theSelf = self... you store subscription to a copy of self. View is a struct.

Comment: ahh.... that simple... me=stupid :) .  Thank you.  So the follow up question - how is it possible to do it with a sink?  the reason I did that is because I couldn't address a mutating self in an escaping closure.   how does one do that - ie create a sink that can mutate values on self - I couldn't find any way of making it compile?

Comment: `.onReceive` actually does `.sink`, and you already know how to use it